# How to get the sum?

Tags: oracle, plsql, count, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have an encountered problem in my query in Oracle SQL. I don't know how to get the sum of this query:

```
select call_type, channel
,count (case when status="no answer" then 1 end else 0) as cnt_no_answer
,count (case when status="answered" then 1 end else 0) as cnt_answer
from app_account.cc_call;
```

Please Help me. Thanks!

Comment: The sum of what?  The query you posted does not appear to be valid without a `group by` clause.

Comment: which column do you want to sum?

Comment: I want to get the sum of no answer and answered

Comment: Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`, and append `GROUP BY call_type, channel` after the table name.

Comment: @kordirko it's not working :( when I use sum instead of count the result is NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the answered and not answered records sum instead of count. To get the number of all records that are either answered or not answered use count(status). To get the count of all records, i.e. also records with status null use count(*). Strings need single quotes, not double quotes. The case statement needs END.

EDITED (there were too many END used):

```
select call_type, channel
  , sum(case when status='no answer' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_no_answer
  , sum(case when status='answered' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_answer
  , count(status) as cnt_all_stated
  , count(*) as cnt_all_records
from app_account.cc_call
group by call_type, channel;
```

Comment: i tried to run your query but all i have got is this ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Yes, sorry, there was "then 1 end else 0 end" which results in a syntax error. There must be no end before else. Sorry I hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 2):

try this again, i edit it:

```
SELECT call_type, channel,
       sum (CASE WHEN status='no answer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_no_answer,
       sum (CASE WHEN status='answered' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_answer
FROM app_account.cc_call
GROUP BY call_type, channel;
```

Comment: There's an error. here's ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 46

Comment: replace `(case when status="no answer" then 1 end else 0)` with `(case when status="no answer" then 1 else 0 end)` and `(case when status="answered" then 1 end else 0)` with `(case when status="answered" then 1 else 0 end)`, there is syntax error

Comment: Here's the new error ORA-00904: "answered": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
SELECT   CALL_TYPE,
       CHANNEL,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN UPPER(STATUS) = UPPER('no answer') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
           AS CNT_NO_ANSWER,
       COUNT (CASE WHEN UPPER(STATUS) = UPPER('answered') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
           AS CNT_ANSWER
FROM   APP_ACCOUNT.CC_CALL
GROUP BY   CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL;
```

Comment: have some error ORA-00904: "answered": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 34

Comment: the query is running but the result in cnt_no_answer and_ cnt_answer is both zero

Comment: can you please send us result of this query: SELECT   CALL_TYPE,
       CHANNEL,
       STATUS, count(*)
FROM   APP_ACCOUNT.CC_CALL
GROUP BY   CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, STATUS;

Comment: Here's the some result of that query for call_type table - LANDLINE
MOBILE-GLOBE
MOBILE-SUN
OTHER
MOBILE-SMART
MOBILE-SUN                           for channel - DAHDI/i1/
SIP/hcsim2
DAHDI/i2/
DAHDI/i1/
DAHDI/i2/
DAHDI/i1/           for status - FAILED
ANSWERED
ANSWERED
NO ANSWER
NO ANSWER
NO ANSWER              for count(*) 1151
1606
4361
137
660
1241

Comment: Yes :) btw.. I want to add in the query this -- WHERE CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE ('29-DEC-13') AND TO_DATE ('04-JAN-14') but all result that i have got is only this  NULL NULL    4465 3392

Comment: Can you provide result of this query: SELECT CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, STATUS, count(*) FROM APP_ACCOUNT.CC_CALL WHERE CALL_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE ('29-DEC-13') AND TO_DATE ('04-JAN-14') GROUP BY CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL, STATUS

Comment: here's the result NULL NULL   NO ANSWER 4465
NULL NULL  FAILED 259
NULL NULL  ANSWERED 3392
NULL NULL  BUSY 429

Comment: It seems data in CALL_TYPE, CHANNEL fields for your desired date priod is null! above result proves this.

Comment: yes because call_type and channel have 39 different data. I tried many time to query the 1week result, but im always failed

Answer (score 1):

select call_type, channel

, sum(case when status='no answer' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_no_answer

, sum(case when status='answered' then 1  else 0 end) as cnt_answer

, count(status) as cnt_all_stated

, count(*) as cnt_all_records

from app_account.cc_call

group by call_type, channel;

why usind end twice

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Call_type, Channel
,COUNT(CASE WHEN status="no answer" then 1 else 0 end ) as Cnt_no_answer
,COUNT(CASE WHEN status="answered" then 1 else 0 end ) as Cnt_answer
from App_account.cc_call 
GROUP BY call_type,channel;
```

I think there is some error in table deceleration. Pleas give table structure. And you want SUM and YOU are COUNTING there I dnt think it is error but lack of overview. Please give some more details.